# sharing the principal object received from an oauth2 provider between spring and angular

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have stumbled upon a problem with Spring Security and Angular.

On my BE (Spring Boot application), there are defined OAuth2 providers, such as Google, GitHub and Facebook.

My BE works fine with this providers, since I can authenticate on the desired providers.

The problem is when I try to send the principal object to the FE (Angular 6 application).

I get undefined value when i try to subscribe the value from the rest endpoint. 
I assume this is due to the Spring Servlet creating a new thread for the login request. 
I am doing my login request from the Angular app.

I did watch dozens of tutorials and rad so many articles, but I just can't find the answer. If it's possible for you to share some code on how it is done, or give me a link, since for sure I am making a silly mistake and can't seem to find the answer here.

Thanks for understanding, have a good day. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the Authorization Code flow from your BE to authenticate the user that interacts with your FE Angular application (you in your example). Otherwise, you would be trying to authenticate the BE Client with the Client flow and you wouldn't need to return the "principal object" to the FE application. If my assumptions are correct... read on.

The Authorization Code flow goes as follows:

1) The user somehow selects an Authentication provider (ex: Google) and that selection is returned to some endpoint in the BE as a non-authenticated request..

2) The BE Client receives this request, preferably intercepted by a filter and, since the request is not authenticatedd, redirects the browser to the selected auth provider's authorization endpoint.

3) The user then proceed to authenticate against that provider which, upon succesfull authentication, returns a response that redirects the browser to a BE Client endpoint. That redirect holds a parameter that provides a code that the BE Client will use to get an idToken representing the user. At this point, it is important to note that **the browser has not been returned any response for this redirect**.

4) The BE Client then proceeds to send a **regular HTTP request** to the provider's token endpoint along with the received authorization code. The provider then returns the idToken an HTTP response directly to the BE Client. All this is happening **while the browser is still waiting for the response to the last redirect**.

5) The BE Client then process the idToken (verification, validation, user details, session etc) and only then, **will finally send the response to the browser** patiently waiting since the code redirect. That response may provide a header or a cookie with a sessionId or token (your choice) that the FE application will be able to read or use for the given purpose.

This flow is relatively easy to implement and requires minimal SS configuration. You must keep the BE Client auth endpoint with permitAll() otherwise, you would not be able to trigger this flow. Also, make sure that, once the FE app. has received the   header/cookie, all subsequent calls shall be processed as "authenticated calls". Finally, make sure to document yourself on the perils of stateless sessions as well as cookie security and always use HTTPS.

Jake.